# Excel data in Powerpoint slide with formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, embed, powerpoint, auto-update

I have some Excel tables that I need to show on a Powerpoint slide, and need them to automatically update if the spreadsheet has been updated.

I can paste them normally, and they look great and I can change column widths, font sizes etc. But the data is static and doesn't update automatically.

Or I can 'Paste Link', which does update automatically, but it looks awful - the text is either squashed or stretched, and if I move the borders it's like stretching a bitmap rather than making more room for the data in the table.

So is there a way of getting the table into Powerpoint, being able to format it well, and also have it updated automatically? I can venture into VBA but this should be possible without code.

Comment: Dumb question possibly, but with the paste/linked version, are you dragging the corner to resize (forces it to resize proportionally) or one of the edges (guaranteed to distort)?

Comment: Yes, I need to change the aspect ratio to get the whole thing to fit onto a page. But it's that the text is just stretched in proportion with the reize, rather than staying the same size and letting me set the font size, like the ordinary paste does. Think I'l need to play around with the formatting in the Excel version, to see if I can get it looking correct when it's pasted, rather than having to stretch it about.

Comment: Yes, change the text size/layout in Excel, not PowerPoint.  What you're working with, once in PPT, is a picture of your data, not the actual Excel content, so unless you stretch by the corners (ie, keep aspect ratio constant), you'll make messes.

Comment: It's actually easier than I expected - if both files are open then the update is instantaneous, and playing with font sizes and row heights (something I would never change in an Excel sheet itself) get it looking good. Thanks for the guidance,

Comment: Glad it helped.  I learned long ago when I was producing zillions of financial slides for a large corporate client that doing tables in Excel was the only sane way of working.  PPT's tables have gotten better, but beyond simple ones ... Excel's the thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you paste as a microsoft chart object it will look a little better.  Also, I've adopted the practice of making a separate tab for my presentation items and adjust the cells there in the excel application instead of in powerpoint.  That way they will stay the same size even when you update your references.

Comment: Will play around with the formatting in Excel to see if it will work. Note that these are cells and data, not charts - charts tend to look great and update themselves too, which is why it's a shame that it's not easy to do the same with tables.